# Could riding a coronal mass ejection to avoid radiation be viable?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, cosmic-radiation

The recent article in The Register [Ten spacecraft – from Venus Express to Voyager 2 – all tracked same solar flare](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/08/17/single_cme_onbserved_by_12_spacecraft/) talks about ten spacecraft noticing the same coronal mass ejection (CME) as it expanded through the system.

It mentions:

> Other craft reported marked decreases in cosmic rays for a day or more
>   as the CME passed

One of the big problems with manned space flight is the exposure to radiation caused by cosmic rays.

Would it be viable to "ride" a CME to reduce the radiation exposure or would this cause all sorts of other issues?

I guess all the electronics on the craft would need serious protection at the very least, but I have little knowledge of CMEs. Keeping up with it's speed is probably something beyond current technology.

Comment: What do you mean by "ride" a CME?  Orbital mechanics means the required ΔV to orient a spacecrafts velocity vector along the CME would be totally impractical.

Comment: No idea really, just wondering if would be possible to stay in that reduced radiation zone created by the CME.

Comment: That's quite an interesting article!

Answer (score 3):

A coronal mass ejection travels at a speed of [between 20 and 3200 km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection). The fastest launch ever (New Horizons) reached 16 km/s, so we can't do this at the moment.

Also, if you were to do this, you'd have to fly through the 'bow wave' of the CME to reach the low-radiation zone. The bow wave is a high-radiation environment. It remains to be seen if the net effect is positive or not.

Comment: *All technical challenges related to velocity aside*, wouldn't the idea be to just time the launch, or phase the exit from Earth's magnetosphere's protection to insert directly into a low radiation zone? Sort-of following the expanding spiral of the ejection out to Mars for example, thereby avoiding the need to fly through the bow wave?

Comment: It may be helpful to include that the linked ESA article in the register gives the actual velocity for this particular event http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Tracking_a_solar_eruption_through_the_Solar_System as does the non-paywalled published paper http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2017JA023884/epdf which also notes "The ICME arrived at Saturn nearly 1 month after its eruption at the Sun..."

Comment: @Hobbes If the CME produces a shock wave, then there are massive regions (that increase with time) before, during, and after that are bathed in energetic particles.  I do not know what you mean by _bow wave_ but there really is no "radiation free" zone for CMEs with shock waves.

Comment: The CME itself consists of high-energy particles. I was picturing it as a wavefront or bow wave of high-energy particles, with a low-radiation zone behind it.